# Merge unversioned directory with versioned directory in SVN

Tags: svn, merge, directory

Is there a way to add a directory that has already been versioned in SVN?

Example:

SVN repository

```
/htdocs
    /directoryinquestion
```

In Sites folder

```
/Sites
   /directoryinquestion
```

What I want to do: merge /Sites/directoryinquestion with /htdocs/directoryinquestion

Problem: Although I can easily copy the directories, the problem is that .svn files get removed and SVN starts to complain.

Any help here would be great. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Try to use svn export the folder (if both have .svn) and then copy that folder's file into your desired folder and svn will automatically detect the new changes made and should be available to add/commit.